# How to Use xpath to echo attributes

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

How can i use xpath to select then echo the data-balance value from the following script?

```
<select class="form-control giftcard-selector" name="giftcard">
<option data-store="Your Awesome!" data-number="NUMBER0" data-pin="NUMBER1" data-balance="NUMBER2" 
value="NUMBER2" style="display: none;">Hello World</option>
</select>
```

I was able to use the following xpath to echo the **Data-store** value, the **data-number** value, and the **data-balance** value and the results are as follows but how can i echo only NUMBER2 which is the **data-balance** value:

```
xpath=//select[@class='form-control giftcard-selector']//option   

Result = "Your Awesome! NUMBER0 NUMBER2"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to echo the data-balance attribute i needed using the following xpath:

```
 xpath=//select[@class="form-control giftcard-selector"]/option@data-balance
```

Result=     NUMBER2

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control giftcard-selector']/option")).getAttribute("data-balance");
```

Hope that this is what you are looking for.